# Trying to write a python program that reads numbers from a file and computes the sum of the squares

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program that reads numbers from a file and then calculates the sum of the squares of the numbers. This program is supposed to prompt the user for the name of the file and print the sum of the squares. It offers a hint that says use readlines() but this hasn't helped me much. I have tried for hours to come up with a working code but can't get anything to work!!! I am about ready to pull my hair out!!! Here is my code:

Code for my file:

```
def main():
    filename = input("Enter the name for the file: ")
    infile = open(filename, 'w')
    numList = input('Enter any numbers(seperated by a space): ')
    print(numList, file=infile)

main()
```

Code for my program:

```
# function to convert list of strings to real numbers
def toNumbers(nums):
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        nums[i] = int(nums[i])

# function to square the numbers in a list
def numsquare(nums):
    for i in range(len(nums)):
    nums[i] = nums[i]**2

# function to add the numbers in the list
def sumList(nums):
    total = 0
    for i in nums:
        total = total + i
    return total

# program that pulls numbers from file and computes sum of the square of the numbers
def main():
fname = input("Please enter the name of the file to be opened: ")
nums = open(fname, 'r')

print("The numbers in this list are:")
print(nums)

# Convert strings in list to actual numbers
toNumbers(nums)
# Square the numbers in the list
numsquare(nums)
# Get the sum of the numbers in the list
sumList(nums)

total = sumList(nums)

print()
print("The sum of the numbers from this list is:", total)


main()
```

If anyone could please tell me what I am doing wrong then it would be greatly appreciated. This is my first ever computer science class and any advice is welcome.

Comment: What does your file look like?

Comment: Note: This is not a valid question format for Stack Overflow. This kind of question would be better on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @ShashankGupta, No this question is perfectly valid on this site.

Comment: I will add it to the original question.

Comment: Thank you all so much for your help. I finally got my code working and you all helped me understand not only what I was doing wrong but also what I was doing. I appreciate it so much and you have saved the hair on my head. I will definitely utilize this site whenever I need help in the future. You all are great!!!

Answer (score 4):

Without knowing the structure of the file, I can at least tell you that part of your problem is that you are using the file handle as your "nums" variable which will not give you your content.

In order to pull the data out of the file you will need to call .read() or .readline() on the file handle.

```
fname = input("Please enter the name of the file to be opened: ")
file = open(fname, 'r')

lines = file.readlines()
```

lines now contains a list where each entry is the content of one line of your file

If you have one number per a line, you should be able to cast the contents of each list entry to an int to get a list of numbers.

If you have multiple numbers per a line, you need to use split() on each list entry to extract each individual number.

Comment: Good answer! You might consider using the [`with` statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) to manage closing the file handle automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The 'readLines()' return a list. Then you have use a for to navigate in list.

```
lines = nums.readlines()
```

The `num` that receive the return of `open(fname, 'r')` is a stream and not a text. Therefore you must use `nums.readlines()` after. See the function `map` of python, is very util to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to debug any code is by printing out at different points to check whether you are getting the desired output.

`nums = open(frame,'r'); print(nums)` You will notice that printing nums does **not** print the contents of the file 'frame'. To get the contents of the file, you need to do `contents = nums.readlines()` or `contents = nums.read()`. The former will give you a list with each entry (which is a string) being one line of the file. The second will give you the entire text converted to a single string.

A sample example is given below:
**my_text_file: say f.txt**

```
12 1 2 3 4 5 6

 8

21 

32

7
```

```
nums = open('f.txt','r')
f = nums.readlines()           #f = nums.read()
>>>['12 1 2 3 4 5 6\n', '\n', ' 8\n', '\n', '21 \n', '\n', '32\n', '\n', '7'] 

#The above line is the output for nums.readlines()

>>>'12 1 2 3 4 5 6\n\n 8\n\n21 \n\n32\n\n7'

#The above line is the output for nums.read()
```

Now you will have to do the appropriate steps to convert the strings to separate the numbers and convert them to int/float and then carry out the calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working program with comments. Let me know if there's anything you don't understand.

Read the comments (marked with #) to better understand some of the stuff that I added.

Also, if you're using Python 3.x, keep using `input()` for input, but if you're using Python 2.x, use `raw_input()` to get input.

```
# function to convert list of strings to real numbers
def toNumbers(nums):
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        nums[i] = int(nums[i])

# function to square the numbers in a list
def numsquare(nums):
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        nums[i] = nums[i]**2

# function to add the numbers in the list
def sumList(nums):
    total = 0
    for i in nums:
        total = total + i
    return total

# program that pulls numbers from file and computes sum of the square of the numbers
def main():
    fname = input("Please enter the name of the file to be opened: ")
    nums = open(fname, 'r')
    strings = ""
    #create a string rather than a list with readlines
    #so we can remove extra spaces with the .split() method later
    for line in nums.readlines():
        strings += line

    #make sure to close nums
    nums.close()

    #remove spaces and store this result in the list nums_array
    nums_array = strings.split()

    print("The numbers in this list are:")
    print(nums_array)

    # Convert strings in list to actual numbers
    toNumbers(nums_array)
    # Square the numbers in the list
    numsquare(nums_array)
    # Get the sum of the numbers in the list
    sumList(nums_array)

    total = sumList(nums_array)

    print
    print("The sum of the numbers from this list is: " + str(total))

main()
```

---

```
>>> Please enter the name of the file to be opened: i.txt
    The numbers in this list are:
    ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']

    The sum of the numbers from this list is: 204
```

where i.txt contains:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```